# ASP classic Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'

Tags: ms-access, iis-7, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm having problem in connecting my MS Access Database. I'm using IIS7. I'm receiving this error:

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no
>   default driver specified

And this is my database connection:

```
<%
 dim rs,con,sql
 SET con=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 SET rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

 con.open "DRIVER={Microsoft Access DRIVER (*.mdb)}; DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("crs.mdb") & ""
 sql="SELECT * FROM tblAccount WHERE fldUsername='"& request.form("txtuser") &"' AND fldPassword='"& request.form("txtpass") &"';"
 rs.CursorType=2

 rs.Open sql, con

 if rs.bof then
   response.write "WRONG"
else
   response.write "CORRECT"
 end if

 rs.Close
 SET rs=Nothing
 SET con=Nothing
%>
```

My unit is Windows & ultimate 64 bit.

Comment: Go to http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/ and pick a better connection string.

Comment: And put a `'` in your form, submit it and see what happens (SQL injection vulnerability)

Comment: where should I exactly put that one?

Comment: @user3130849 please read about SQL Injection attacks then about classic ASP command parameters. After reading you'll know what I mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried enabling 32 bit applications support in IIS?

http://help.webcontrolcenter.com/KB/a1114/how-to-enable-32-bit-application-pool-iis-7-dedicatedvps.aspx